# Check Page requested, and redirect

Tags: redirect

I am trying to capture what page is being requested, then drop a cookie and (ultimately will forward on), but for now just echoing a result and then exiting. The page I am looking for is called **checkpage** This is not a Wordpress page or post - it doesn't exist, but if requested, I want to perform this action.

I am hooking the wp action to do a check on the page request

```
add_action('wp', [$this,"checkRequest"],1);
```

Then picking this up as below

```
 public function checkRequest($request) {
    if ($request instanceof \WP)
    {
        $queryVars = $request->query_vars;    
    
        if (is_array($queryVars))
        {
            $isMyPage = false;
            if (isset($queryVars["pagename"]) && $queryVars["pagename"] == 'checkpage') {
                $isMyPage = true;
            } else {
                if (isset($queryVars["name"]) && $queryVars["name"] == 'checkpage') {
                    $isMyPage = true;
            }

            if ($isMyPage) {
                setcookie("MyPage", "yes", time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); //30 days                    
                echo "MyPage cookie set for 30 days";                    
                die();
            }

        }            
    }
```

This function is working on a single site, but if I run on a multisite, it fires twice. The first time it fires, the $query_vars is set as below

```
array(1) (
   [error] => (string) 404
)
```

The second time it fires, the array is empty.

Is there a better way to check the page requested at an early enough stage to catch a non-existent page and then perform a function and redirect?

Comment: do not think of the `WP` object as a request object, that's not what it is or how it works. `WP` is basically an assorted jumble bag of things that need somewhere to live that's rarely used in plugin/theme development. What you're doing here is unusual, especially on that hook and in the way that you've done it. It would have been much easier to ask "How do I redirect from this page to another" which has lots of existing answers that are more useful to you, and answer this question indirectly

Comment: also it's not clear how you're testing this, there is no debug code in your question to log what the query vars are, so it's not possible to explain the behaviour you're having trouble with. However, if it's as I suspect an `error_log` call, then you've fallen into the trap of assuming all requests are frontend requests, and forgotten about AJAX/CLI/Cron/REST/Admin requests

Comment: Thanks - taking on board what you have said, I am now using the wp_loaded action and checking against $_SERVER variables to pull out the url. Also checking if cron or ajax.

Comment: that's better but still not normal most people use a hook such as `template_redirect`